# Batch script variable is printed as such

Tags: batch-file

I have written a batch script which creates a folder. The path is given as a input parameter and the folder name is today' s date.

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b
set TODAY=%day%_%month%_%year%
mkdir %1% %TODAY%
```

and the output I get is as follows:

```
arvind_test.bat C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\logs\ C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\logs\

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %a in ('date /T') do set year=%c

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>set year=2013

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %a in ('date /T') do set month=%a

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>set month=04

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %a in ('date /T') do set day=%b

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>set day=16

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>set TODAY=16_04_2013

C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\zip\test>mkdir C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\logs\TODAY
A subdirectory or file C:\Users\M1015807\Desktop\logs\TODAY already exists.
>> was unexpected at this time.
```

Can any one help please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric `%` variables aren't supposed to be surrounded by `%`, they just have a leading `%`. The expression:

```
mkdir %1% %TODAY%
```

has the following elements:

- `mkdir`;
- `%1` (note, *not* using the following `%` symbol);
- `% %` (an empty string most likely);
- TODAY (the *literal* string `TODAY`); and
- a naked `%` at the end (which, from memory, also gives you an empty string).

You can see this in the following script:

```
@echo off
set TODAY=blah
echo mkdir %1% %TODAY%
```

which, if you call it as `myscript.cmd hello`, gives you:

```
mkdir helloTODAY
```

Changing the script to:

```
@echo off
set TODAY=blah
echo mkdir %1 %TODAY%
```

(removing the `%` immediately after the `1`) gives you more like what you want (although your *actual* code probably has a `\` separating the path and directory, rather than a space as per your example):

```
mkdir hello blah
```

Comment: Hi Thanks paxdiablo I have been new to writing batch script. It is working fine. And thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

A couple observations about your code, and an important point at end.

`%date%` variable show the same information of `date /t` command, but the former is more efficient. The execution of a command in FOR requires a copy of cmd.exe and the creation of a temporary file. The replacement of a variable value is immediate:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do ...
```

`tokens=2-4` provide access to three pieces of information *in the same FOR command*, so it is not necessary to execute it three times:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set year=%%c
   set month=%%a
   set day=%%b
)
```

If you are using three previous variables with the sole purpose to assemble TODAY variable, then the variables are not necessary:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set TODAY=%%b_%%a_%%c
```

If you are using TODAY variable with the sole purpose to create the folder, then it is not necessary either:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do mkdir %1 %%b_%%a_%%c
```

The important point now:

`mkdir` command creates separated folders if they are separated by space. This command creates *two* folders: `mkdir one two`. You should eliminate the space between the path and the folder name: `mkdir %1%%b_%%a_%%c`. However, if the path given in first parameter may contain spaces, it must be enclosed in quotes: `arvind_test.bat "C:\Users\Joe Doe\M1015807\Desktop\logs"`, but the quotes must be removed from the parameter this way: `%~1` AND the complete folder name must be enclosed in quotes:

```
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do mkdir "%~1%%b_%%a_%%c"
```